# Error while uploading tvOS app

Tags: tvos

I got the following errors:

> - ERROR ITMS-90528: "Invalid Image Asset. The image asset 'App Icon - Small' in 'Payload/Projectname.app' has an invalid scale value of '0'.
>     Home Screen Icon assets are allowed scale values of ( "1" ).
> - ERROR ITMS-90523: "Invalid Image Asset. The image stack 'App Icon - Small' in 'Payload/Projectname.app/Assets.car' can't have a
>     transparent background layer.
> - ERROR ITMS-90531: "Invalid Image Asset. The image stack 'App Icon - Small' in 'Payload/Projectname.app/Assets.car' must have a background
>     layer that's 400x240 pixels.
> - ERROR ITMS-90532: "Invalid Image Asset. The image stack 'App Icon - Small' in 'Payload/Projectname.app/Assets.car' has an incorrectly
>     positioned background layer.

I checked everything and both the small and big sized icons for the tvOS app are on the perfect size, background is without transparency and on the size as needed. Both looks perfect on the preview and on the actual Apple TV system.

The icons assent was created from the formal Photoshop plugin Apple supplied. No clue where to go from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that making all layers of the icon full size solved the problem. Means not using the location of the layer but making the asset in a way the location is already on the full sized layer.

Just to make clear, All layers of the small icon (400 x 240 pixels) are with 400x 240 size with transparency except for the background layer which is without transparency offcourse.

Seems like a very odd bug so I though publishing it.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days trying to solve the ERROR ITMS-90523 this was what it was happening to me:

The error uploading my app said the App Icon **Small** was wrong. At the end yes, it was a problem because one image had a transparent background layer but it was in the background App Icon **LARGE**!! Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Answer (score 0):

TvOS upload - error said the problem is with **App Icon** stack. The problem was actually in the **App Icon - App Store** stack. Removing aplha channel in the Preview app solved it.